# How are dimensions and fact tables related in a star diagram?

Tags: data-warehouse

If you have a relational database and you want to start making reports, you might do the following (please let me know if this is incorrect).

1. Go through your relational database and make a list of all the columns that you want to include in your report.
2. Group related columns together and then split those (normalise) into additional tables. These are the dimensions.
3. The dimensions then have a primary key (possibly a combination of two rows), and the fact table has a foreign key to reference each dimension, plus fields that you don't separate out in the first place such as sales value.

The question:
I was originally seeing dimensions as data marts that referenced data from external sources, and a fact table that in turn referenced data in the dimensions.. that's incorrect, isn't it? It's the other way around...

Or in general, if you were to normalise a database you would always replace the columns you take out a table with a foreign key, and add a primary key to the new table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fact table represents a process or event that you want to analyze.

**Step 1**: What is the process or event that you want to analyze?

The columns in the fact table represent all of the variables that are pertinent to your analysis.

**Step 2**: What variables are pertinent to the analysis?

Whether you "split-out" columns into dimension tables is irrelevant to your understanding. It's an optimization to minimize the space taken up by fact tables.

If you want to discriminate between measures and dimensions, ask

**Step 3**: What are the (true) numeric values in my fact table? These are your measures.

An example of a true numeric value is a dollar amount, like Sales Order Line Item Extended Price. You can sum it up or take an average of it.

An example of a not true numeric value is Customer ID 12345. It's a number, but represents something that isn't a number (a customer). The sum of customer ids makes no sense, nor does the average. Dig?

Regarding your questions:

1. Fact tables do not need foreign keys to dimension tables. (hint: see Hot-Swappable Dimensions)
2. "dimensions as data marts that referenced data from external sources". Hm...maybe, but don't worry about data marts for now. A dimension is just a column in your fact table (that isn't a measure). A dimension table is just a collection of dimensions that are related.
3. Just start with Excel. Figure out the columns you need in your analysis. Put them in Excel. That's your fact table. If you expect your fact table to get large (100s of MB), then do ONE level of normalization:

Figure out your measures. Leave them in the fact table.

Figure out your dimensions. Group them together (Customer info into one group, Store info into another).

Put them in their own tables. Give them meaningless surrogate keys. Put those keys in the fact table.